# public function doesn't exist in plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Trying to make a simple jquery plugin, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It's design to make a multi-step form, which was working fine. The logic of the prevPage and nextPage methods were basically the same so I was moving the logic to setPage() instead then calling it from the other two public methods.  All 3 methods should be public and from outside the plugin this works fine. The following example works just fine, I can set the page to whatever from that method call.  But I can't call setPage from prevPage or nextPage, it says the function doesn't exist.  I imagine it's a scope issue but can't figure out what I've done wrong.

Example:

```
    $thing = $('#demo').book();
    

    $('#myButton').on('click', function(){
        $thing.setPage(2);
    });
```

Plugin

```
(function($){
$.fn.book = function(options){
    
    var defaults = {
        onPageChange: function(){},
        speed: 500
    };
    
    var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
    
    
    if (this.length > 1){
        this.each(function(){ $(this).book(options) });
        return this;
    }
    
    var pageIndex = 0;
    
    var $this = $(this);
    
    var pages = $this.children('section').css({width:'100%',height:'100%',position:'relative'}); 
    
    
    
    this.initialize = function(){
        
        pages.hide();
        pages.first('section').show();
        
        pages.find('.page-next').on('click', this.nextPage);
    
        pages.find('.page-prev').on('click', this.prevPage);
        
        return this;
    }
    
    
    
    this.getPageIndex = function(){
        return pageIndex;
    }
    
    
    this.getPageCount = function(){
        return pages.length;
    }
    

    
    this.setPage = function(index){
        
        if (index >= 0 && index < pages.length && index != pageIndex){
            
            oldPageIndex = pageIndex; // retain for callback info
            $currentPage = pages.eq(pageIndex);
            $newPage     = pages.eq(index);
            pageIndex    = index;
            pageName     = ($newPage[0].hasAttribute("name")) ? $newPage.attr('name') : null;  // used in callback
            
            
            if (typeof settings.onPageChange == 'function'){
                settings.onPageChange.call(this, oldPageIndex, pageIndex, pages.length, pageName );
            }
            
            
            if (index > pageIndex){ // move forward
            
                $currentPage.hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, settings.speed, function(){
                    $newPage.show("slide", {direction:"right"}, settings.speed);
                });
                
            }else{ // move back
                
                $currentPage.hide("slide", {direction:"right"}, settings.speed, function(){
                    $newPage.show("slide", {direction:"left"}, settings.speed);
                });
                
            }
            
        }
        return this;
    };
    
    
    
    
    this.nextPage = function(){
        
        return $this.setPage(pageIndex+1);

    };
    
    
    
    
    this.prevPage = function(){
        
        return this.setPage(pageIndex-1);
        
    };

    
    return this.initialize();
};


}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the logic of setPage into a private method called changePage(), then called that from the public methods.  This seemed to work fine.  This is probably better design practice anyway.